# Problems in setting up Visual Studio 2012 for Remote Debugging

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2012, remote-debugging

I have problems in setting up Visual Studio 2012 for Remote Debugging. In the first place, I don’t see the option, in the Properties page of my project Debug->Start Options, “Target device” as in this page stated:

http://hsballina.wordpress.com/2012/11/20/remote-debugging-in-visual-studio-2012-on-windows-8/

Actually, the options are different from my project:

[image]

Why is that? is it because my project is for “Windows Forms Application” and not targeted to Windows 8?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

WinForms project does not support deploying on remote machines, which means that you cannot setup F5 experience out-of-box for this kind of projects. 
To debug your application on remote machine - you can do

1. build  and deploy your app (copy manually)
2. launch Remote Debugger on remote machine
3. launch app on remote machine
4. in VS launch Attach To Process diaglod (Debug -> Attach to process).
5. choose remote machine in Qualifier field.
6. choose your process in list of processes and click Attach.